Die korrekte Anwendung des Wortes "Digger" / "Digga"
Besonders häufig verwenden die Schulkinder das Wort "Digga". Wie ich verstehe, es ist ein Synonym von "Kerl", "Kumpel" ,"Kollege" usw. Wobei (so wurde mir gesagt)  "ein netter Digga" ist falsch. Auch gibt es angeblich kein Mehrzahl von "Digga" wie z. B., "Diggas".
Wie funktioniert dieses Wort und in welchen Fällen wird  es korrekt verwendet?

"Digga" ist eine verwaschene Aussprache von "Dicker". Das könnte man auf den ersten Blick für eine Beleidigung halten, wie "Hey, Fettsack!". So ist es aber nicht gemeint.
Stattdessen wird der Begriff in der Regel zwischen Freunden verwendet, oder zumindest zwischen Menschen, die sich kennen und sich gegenseitig einschätzen können. Es ist mehr eine freundschaftliche Frotzelei, wenn jemand einen Freund mit zum Beispiel "Hey, Digga, wie geht's?" begrüßt. Vergleichbar wäre etwas wie "Hallo, Doofkopf!".
Eben weil es von einem Freund kommt (oder jedenfalls von einer Person, von der man weiß, dass es nicht ernst und als Beleidigung gemeint ist), kann der Angesprochene es als Frotzelei oder freundschaftliches Necken einordnen. Dabei unterstützen der Kontext, der Tonfall, die Mimik (zum Beispiel ein Lächeln) und so weiter.
Generell sollte man "Digga" nur mit Personen verwenden, die man gut genug kennt. Wenn der Angesprochene nicht einschätzen kann, wie Du das "Digga" gemeint hast, könnte es zu Missverständnissen führen. Außerdem könnte es mehr Vertrautheit signalisieren, als der Angesprochene zu diesem Zeitpunkt zugestehen möchte ("Wer ist der, dass er mich 'Digga' nennt?").
Wichtig ist natürlich auch, was in der jeweiligen sozialen Gruppe üblich ist. Wenn man neu in eine Gruppe von Freunden, Nachbarn, Arbeitskollegen o. ä. kommt, und alle sprechen sich unter einander mit "Digga" an, kann man das auch einmal versuchen, und dann auf die Reaktionen achten.

Vielen Dank für die interessante Infos! Da möchte ich noch verstehen warum verhält sich dieses Wort nicht als ein Nomen bzw. warum sind die oben genannte Fälle falsch.

@int21h--GlorytoUkraine-- Ich kann nicht beurteilen, was sprachwissenschaftlich dahintersteckt, aber ich würde "Digga" als eine Art Namen oder Spitznamen betrachten. Die werden ja auch in einigen Fällen anders als gewöhnliche Nomen verwendet.

Das Wort wird üblicherweise nur als Form der Anrede in der Jugendsprache verwendet und hat als generelles Wort keinen Eingang in die Sprache gefunden. Jeder würde es verstehen, wenn man sagt "ein netter Digga", aber es wäre eher untypisch, aber nicht falsch, wenn das jemand tun würde. Dagegen habe ich schon von "Diggies" als Mehrzahl gehört, aber bei solchen Wörtern überbietet man sich oft in der Kreativität, d.h. nichts ist fix, und je verrückter, um so besser... "Digs", "Diggas" wären auch denkbar, aber stehen deswegen noch lange nicht im Duden. ;-)

Ich könnte mir im übrigen auch einen Einfluss von "dicke sein" für "eng befreundet sein" vorstellen. Dann ist ein "Dicker > Digga" jemand mit dem man dicke ist, also ein enger Freund.

(Lustigerweise kennt der Duden "dicke sein" nicht in dieser Bedeutung, sondern als 1. "etwas/jemandes überdrüssig sein"; 2. "reichlich" https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dicke.)

Ah, der Duden hat es als bedeutung des Adjektivs dick, in dieser Lesart ist "die sind dicke" eine Ellipse für "die sind dicke Freunde", siehe Bedeutung 6 von https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dick.

@SebastianRiese: Das steht aber in ziemlichem Widerspruch zur Aussage, dass "Digga" nur in der 2. Person Singular verwendet wird.

Aus meiner Sicht nicht, da ja eine Anrede aus einer anderen Form entstehen kann, oder zumindest von dieser Variante beeinflusst sein kann. Volksetymologie ist ja oft am Spiel dabei, wenn sich ein Wort durchsetzt. (Wikipedia hält im übrigen einen einfluss von "dicke sein" auch für möglich).
